# Source information is missing from the debug information for this module in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

While debugging the code in visual studio 2012 I'm encountering this particular issue :

**Source information is missing from the debug information for this module.**

Unable to proceed with any further operations :( Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After loads of research.... Since it's a silverlight project and found that deleting ZAP and rebuilding the solution made the magic to remove this issue :)

Comment: What is zap and how did you delete it?